# HTML5 Bootstrap3: Display side-by-side credit card expiration month and year?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I've been using Bootstrap v3 to make a mobile friendly payment form/application. I'm having some difficulty showing side-by-side fields (2) together with the normal text field. There's a credit card expiration month and a credit card expiration year. When changing the page width the label/fields don't adjust in the same way. The dropdowns are also difficult to read at times. Should I just apply a fixed with to the dropdowns? Any suggestions? See JSFiddle example.

https://jsfiddle.net/1dnqLb8r/

Full Screen

https://jsfiddle.net/1dnqLb8r/embedded/result/

```
<div class="container">
<fieldset>
    <legend>Credit Card Information</legend>
    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="AccountNo" id="AccountNo_label">* Card Number</label>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <input id="AccountNo" name="AccountNo" type="tel" value="1234123412341234" placeholder="Debit / Credit Card Number" class="form-control input-md" required=""> <span class="help-block" style="display: none;">Enter a valid debit or credit card number. Spaces will be shown automatically.</span> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="CCMonth">* Card Expiration</label>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <select class="form-control col-sm-2" name="CCMonth" id="CCMonth">
                        <option>Month</option>
                        <option value="01" Selected>Jan (01)</option>
                        <option value="02">Feb (02)</option>
                        <option value="03">Mar (03)</option>
                        <option value="04">Apr (04)</option>
                        <option value="05">May (05)</option>
                        <option value="06">June (06)</option>
                        <option value="07">July (07)</option>
                        <option value="08">Aug (08)</option>
                        <option value="09">Sep (09)</option>
                        <option value="10">Oct (10)</option>
                        <option value="11">Nov (11)</option>
                        <option value="12">Dec (12)</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <select class="form-control" name="CCYear">
                        <option>Year</option>
                        <option value="15" selected>2015</option>
                        <option value="16">2016</option>
                        <option value="17">2017</option>
                        <option value="18">2018</option>
                        <option value="19">2019</option>
                        <option value="20">2020</option>
                        <option value="21">2021</option>
                        <option value="22">2022</option>
                        <option value="23">2023</option>
                        <option value="24">2024</option>
                        <option value="25">2025</option>
                        <option value="26">2026</option>
                        <option value="27">2027</option>
                        <option value="28">2028</option>
                        <option value="29">2029</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div> <span class="help-block" style="display: none;">Select the card expiration date month and year.</span> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for. I recreated your layout and left it sparse so you could see what I did and how it compares to your code. Basically, I think you were getting mixed up with the `cols`, which is **really** easy to do. :)

```
<div class="container">
    <form class="form-horizontal">

        <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">Card Number</label>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>

        <label class="col-sm-5 control-label">Card Expiration</label>
        <div class="col-sm-7">
            <!-- wrap in a .row to remove padding so it matches input:text field -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select class="form-control">
                            <option>Year</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- offset by 1 so it's not smashed up to the year select -->
                <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <select class="form-control">
                            <option>Month</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, I see. So, even the internal "row" has to total out to 12, not 7? That is 6+5+1 = 12.

Comment: You don't *have* to do twelve if you don't want to - you'll just have spaces if they don't add up to 12. I added the `.col-sm-offset-1` class so the month select wasn't touching the year select. But, generally, yes, you can nest as many as you want and each will add up to 12.

Comment: I finally got it to display in all widths. I had to remove your "<div class="form-group">" divs from the above code. Was there a reason for those divs?

Comment: They're not required, just adds formatting. Glad you got it working. :)